Hibernate second level cache usage with jpa issue
Case i want to recreate:

Application startup and put one table from postgres DB to cache
All querys to this table must be executed and use second level cache instead of DB connection.

build.gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-jcache:6.1.6.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.ehcache:ehcache:3.10.8'
}

application.properties:
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class= 
org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Cache initialization:
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    private final RegionsRepo repo;

    public CacheConfig(RegionsRepo repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initCache() {
        repo.findAll().forEach(region -> {});
    }
}

Entity annotations:
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY) 
@Table(name = "regions")

And JpaRepository:
public interface RegionsRepo extends JpaRepository<Regions, Long> {
    
    Optional<Regions> findRegionsByExternalid(Integer id);

    @Override
    Optional<Regions> findById(Long aLong);

    @Override
    @QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.CACHEABLE, value = "true"))
    List<Regions> findAll();
}

After starup app puts table into second level hibernate cache. Log:
 346333 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    73250 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    1098084 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    5962251 nanoseconds spent performing 3 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    368667 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    68458 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)

when i call repository method

findById

which is Overrided from JpaRepository, i see that there is no execution of JDBC statement, just pure L2C hits which is what i needed.
Log:
    1277291 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    418709 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)

BUT when i use custom, not overrided method

findRegionsByExternalid

L2C hits is ignored. Log:
742083 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
849083 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
2029042 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
670583 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)

Could you please tell what is wrong with hibernate cache configuration in this case?
And what should i do to make hibernate use L2C cache at non-overrided JpaRepository methods?

About your second one, but it is acquiring, preparing and executing it. So it is managed by this module.

In my case there are puts..sometimes, however there are no 2 other ones. However they should be..?

Yes, it should. So it is downscoped to BL or PL layers in one application.

finally solve by myself.
Since hibernate-jcache default provider can search by Entity id which is primary key, i just recreate Entity in DB without id.
Signature before:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;
Integer externalid;
String externalname;
Integer internalid;
String internalname;

here we can scan and search at L2C just using Long id field.
to:
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
Integer externalid;
String externalname;
Integer internalid;
String internalname;

Now Long id kind of equals to externalid and i can search by it in L2C cache.
